# Texture Alpha Background not showing properly in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to add to my three.js render some flowers exported as GLtf from Blender, with alpha textures. However, the object is imported in a weird way, and it does not look as it does in some GLtf previewers online:
[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f146Z.jpg) vs. [GLtf previewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHu0F.png)

This is the code, what should I add to fix this?

```
let loadingUrl = `assets/images/blender/Flower Bush.glb`;
/** Loading the resorce with GLTF Loader */
loader.load(
  loadingUrl,
  (gltf) => {
    gltf.scene.position.x = this.maxXPointFromArray / 2;
    gltf.scene.position.z = this.minYPointFromArray / 2;
    //gltf.scene.position.y = -0.3;
    gltf.scene.rotateY(-THREE.Math.degToRad(0));
    gltf.scene.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
    gltf.scene.traverse((obj) => {
      obj.castShadow = true;
      obj.receiveShadow = true;
      if (obj instanceof THREE.Mesh && obj.material.name == "Furban") {
        obj.material.polygonOffsetFactor = -4;
        obj.material.polygonOffset = true;

      }
    });
    this.scene.add(gltf.scene);


    gltf.animations; // Array<THREE.AnimationClip>
    gltf.scene; // THREE.Scene
    gltf.scenes; // Array<THREE.Scene>
    gltf.cameras; // Array<THREE.Camera>
    gltf.asset; // Object
  },
  /** Progress for model loading */
  (xhr) => {
    console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded');
  },
  /** Error on model loading */
  (error) => {
    console.log('An error happened', error);
  }
);
```

Comment: Try to start with this: `obj.material.alphaTest = 0.5`. Configuring polygon offset should not be necessary.